# Delete bulk responses from google sheet using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, google-sheets, google-forms

I am currntly working on macro design for uploading my data at google sheet using vba,now data upload is fine and my current requirement is delete all uploaded data using vba.My current working code for uploading data at google sheet is given.

My working code is given below.

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d   /e/1FAIpQLSf7klU18JBxp7wZJrr5bjScJ_SJCgNIJO58l76kKIcoXc2S63w/formResponse" & _
"?ifq&entry.1324774294=" & Field2 & "&entry.1969576980=" & Field1 &  "&entry.988253828=" & field3
With HTTPreq
.Open "POST", url, False
.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 .Send
 End With
```

Comment: Did you do web search? I did and saw several presentations (some YouTube) on this topic. Or try the GoogleSheet macro recorder to get you some sample code to adapt.

Comment: thanks for your feedback,actually i am updating date with data extraction from other site using chrome selenium,so if is use google sheet macro then records will be deleted during extraction and uploading.what i want is when i start fresh extraction then first i will delete whole form responses using http method.